# I tried charging my earbuds with OTG on a USB type A to A cable. But it got damaged. Why?

Tags: battery-charging, usb-c

I have a USB type A to A cable. I connected an OTG (type A to C) on one end and an adapter on the other end. I then tried charging my earbuds case with it. The case got really hot while charging and now it no longer charges. I want to know what went wrong with my connection and what got damaged within the earbuds case.

Comment: You will have to specify the way in which you charged your earbuds. Looking at the voltage and current ratings of whatever charger you used as well as that supported by your earbuds is important. Also, from what I came to know from other users on this site, Type-A to Type-A cable is forbidden. Try to avoid those cables wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing consumer electronics without knowing enough about subject is off-topic here.

However, here's an explanation of what happened. Your earbud charger is now damaged because you used a non-standard and dangerous USB cable which allowed you to make connections that standard USB cables will not allow.

USB cables with Type-A plugs on both ends are "illegal" by the USB specs, they should not exist or be manufactured because they allow consumers to make connections that make no sense and can damage things.

Now, as it does exist, it means it could be a special dangerous cable, used for some obscure purpose on rare occasions. Maybe some cheap chinese device has Type-A socket intended for hosts due to a design error while it should have Type-B socket, so the non-standard device came with a non-standard cable.

As an analogy, you should not have mains extension cords with mains plugs on both ends either, even if these special dangerous cables could be used for some obscure purpose on rare occasions, but under normal use, these are dangerous and do damage.

As an exception, the USB cables with Type-A plugs are allowed to exist as USB3 debug cables, if they don't pass the power supply wire between devices. Clearly, your cable was not an allowed debug cable.

And the Type-C plug to Type-A socket adapter you used should be an allowed adapter, but it is made to provide a Type-A host/charger socket on a Type-C host socket, not to provide a device side socket. So using the adapter with the dangerous cable allowed you to damage the earphone charger.